# Pointers to Dynamic Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I am trying to learn how to create a function that will take a dynamic int array (int *arrayPtr = (int*) malloc...) and replace it with another dynamic array. This new array will not simply be of different values, but potentially a different number of elements.

From my research, I've learned that I need to pass into this function a reference to my array pointer, rather than the pointer itself (&arrayPtr). That means the function signature needs to have int **arrayPtr instead of int *arrayPtr.

I feel like it makes sense to me; We need to tell arrayPtr to point to a different location in memory, so we need the memory address of arrayPtr rather than its value (the memory address of the original array);

I wrote a little test program to see if I understood, but I cannot get it to work. Using debugging, I've observed the following: From within the function, the (int **arrayPtr) doesn't represent the entire array, but just the first element. That is, I can get the value 500 if I do *arrayPtr[0], but *arrayPtr[1] is inaccessible memory.

Here is my test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void replaceArray(int **arrayPtr, unsigned int arrayLength) {

    int i;
    int *tempArrayPtr;

    tempArrayPtr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * arrayLength);

    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        tempArrayPtr[i] = *arrayPtr[i] * 2;
    }

    free(arrayPtr);

    arrayPtr = &tempArrayPtr;

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;
    int arrayLength = 2;
    int *arrayPtr;

    arrayPtr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * arrayLength);
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        arrayPtr[i] = i + 500;
    }

    replaceArray(&arrayPtr, arrayLength);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The function is supposed create a new array with the value of each element of the original array doubled, and have the arrayPtr variable in the calling function refer to the new array instead. As i have written it, however, it gets SIGSEGV when the replaceArray function tries to access *arrayPtr[1].

I realize that this little demonstration program is not doing anything that requires the behavior that I'm testing. It is just so that I can understand the concept with a simple example.

Since this is a tiny, trivial, program, I feel justified in that the answer that I accept will contain the complete working version of this code.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below code and the inline comments.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void replaceArray(int **arrayPtr, unsigned int arrayLength) {

    int i;
    int *tempArrayPtr;

    tempArrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * arrayLength);  //do not cast

    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        tempArrayPtr[i] = (*arrayPtr)[i] * 2;
    }

    free(*arrayPtr);  // free the *arrayPtr, [which is `arrayPtr` from `main`]

    *arrayPtr = tempArrayPtr;   //copy tempArrayPtr and put it into *arrayPtr

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;
    int arrayLength = 2;
    int *arrayPtr;

    arrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * arrayLength);  // do not cast
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        arrayPtr[i] = i + 500;
    }

    replaceArray(&arrayPtr, arrayLength);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. The third change is something that I had tried, but I had no idea about the first. I'm going to have to look into why it behaves like that.

I am curious why you say not to cast malloc. I'm a student now and every single example of malloc in the course material is cast.

Comment: @donald I'm just out for lunch. I'll reply to your queries.  Meanwhile you can visit the link in my comment to get the answer related to casting.

Comment: That is a very interesting thread. It appears to be an ongoing controversy, whether to cast or not. The argument against casting had about 4 times more +1s, but the argument for casting was more coherent. I'm not sure what camp I'm in, then.

Answer (score 2):

There have to be three changes in you code:

```
void replaceArray(int **arrayPtr, unsigned int arrayLength) {

    int i;
    int *tempArrayPtr;

    tempArrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * arrayLength);

    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
            tempArrayPtr[i] = (*arrayPtr)[i] * 2;//In this if you use the without braces it will acts array of pointers that is pointing to a array. So we have to get the value from that using that braces.
    }
    free(*arrayPtr);//<< here we have to free the memory of arrayPtr not the address of the &arrayPtr.

    *arrayPtr = tempArrayPtr; // Here you have to assign the address to that value of arrayPtr.

    return;
}
```

> There is no need the type cast the return value of malloc.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these lines are wrong:

```
free(arrayPtr);
arrayPtr = &tempArrayPtr;
```

The first line passes the address of your variable to `free()`, rather than the address of the actual allocated array. Since the variable is on the stack rather than mallocated, `free()` will crash or abort here. What you want to do instead is `free(*arrayPtr):`.

The second line merely sets the local variable `arrayPtr` to the address of the variable `tempArrayPtr`. What you want to do instead is `*arrayPtr = tempArrayPtr;`.